# Woocommerce - Is it possible to hide a product category based on the stock status of the products that are under this category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I tried to hide a category from my shop based on the factor that this category does not contain even 1 product that is in stock. If even 1 product is in stock then the category will appear.

I tried something like the code below with no avail:

```
function hide_out_of_stock_categories( $list_args ){
 if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() ){
            $list_args[ 'hide_empty' ] = 1;
            return $list_args;
}
}
```

I need to search first for the products inside the category and then check if the product stock status is in stock or out of stock, but I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

To hide or remove the empty categories listed here, add the following code lines at the end of your theme’s functions.php file.

```
function woo_hide_product_categories_widget( $list_args ){
 
      $list_args[ 'hide_empty' ] = 1;
 
      return $list_args;
 
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'woo_hide_product_categories_widget' )
```

Comment: This will hide the empty categories. But I want to check first if all the products inside of that category that have an out of stock status. So even if one product is in stock, then the category must remain visible. If all the products that are inside this category are out of stock, then the category will be hidden.